# Сохранение в переменную Js Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, массивы

Есть массив элементов, полученный из ajax запроса

```
        var tutajax2 = $.ajax("otobr.php") 
    .done(function(data) { 
    $.each(JSON.parse(data) , function (key , value) 
{ 
    $template = `${value.fname} ${value.sname} ${value.score}\n`; 
    console.log($template);
}); 
}) 
.fail(function() { 
console.log("ne ochen"); 
    });
```

Мне необходимо первый элемент массива занести в одну переменную, второй во вторую, третий в третью и т.д.

Comment: "занести в одну переменную, второй во вторую ..." - что это за переменные?

Comment: просто переменные index1, index2, index3, ..., index10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var holder = {};
var tutajax2 = $.ajax("otobr.php")
  .done(function(data) {
    $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(key, value) {
      holder["index" + key] = `${value.fname} ${value.sname} ${value.score}\n`;
    });
    console.log(holder);
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log("ne ochen");
  });
```

Comment: Выбило ошибку `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)` в этой строке `$.each(JSON.parse(data), function(key, value) {`

Comment: я извиняюсь, эта строка была в Вашем коде. Ваш код работал? `console.log(typeof data, data);`

Comment: Блин. Ну вроде как да, работал. Щас попробую здесь же попробую спросить, что за ошибка

Comment: Запрос сработал. Вывело всё как нужно с индексами, но вопрос в том как присвоить эти значения из запроса, обычным переменным

Comment: @ВладКислюк без использования `eval` - никак. Может Вы объясните, какую задачу Вы пытаетесь решить?